# Select from table where table = id if session is lang_code

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select the english menu title with  if session and my current sql table "see code"

```
if($_SESSION['lang_code'] == 'en') {
    echo $courseCat['course_cat_title'];
} else 
    echo $courseCat['course_cat_title'];
```

it prints so far good but only the dutch menu title, when I look in my DB I have this table that shows the language country id  **course_cat_lang_country**, now I need to know how I can print the English title when page is www.yourdomain.nl/en/. the full code that I use now is this.

```
$QcourseCat = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM web_course_cat WHERE course_cat_id = 1");
$courseCat = mysql_fetch_assoc($QcourseCat);
echo "< h4>";

if($_SESSION['lang_code'] == 'en') { 
    echo $courseCat['course_cat_title'];  
} else 
    echo $courseCat['course_cat_title']; 

echo "< h4>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
if($_SESSION['lang_code'] == 'en') {
    $table='course_cat_eng'; 
}
else {
    $table='course_cat_title';
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE course_cat_id = 1";
if (! $resource = mysql_query($sql) ){
    echo "Error reading from table $table";
}
else {
    if (!mysql_num_rows($resource ) ){
        echo "No records foin in $table";
    }
    else {
        $courseCat = mysql_fetch_assoc($resource);
        echo "<h4>";
        echo $courseCat['course_cat_title']; 
        echo "</h4>";
        //...
        // other stuff you might want to do
    }
}
```

Please comment if this is not what you are looking for, and I will revise my answer.

Comment: If my answer is helpful, please upvote or accept it. If not, please comment below, and I will revise and improve my answer.

Comment: I have take a look at your code when I had this problem, I adjust it here and there with your code and it works now, so thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't sorting your results to check the language country id.  You are getting only the first row.  You need to change the query to get the language that you want.  Or loop through the results that you get checking which language they are.

In the code that you posted your `if` statement does the same thing in each branch.  And you never use it to select data.

Also as per the comments use MYSQLi or PDO for your querys as MYSQL is deprecated.